# CSS borders do not reach across the full width of a scrollable div

Tags: css

**Problem**
[image: preview]

The border-bottom stops where to scrolling starts. How to fix this? I tried setting width of 100% on those div's, but that did'nt seem to help.

See Fiddle
**https://jsfiddle.net/exrb8oma/**

**CSS**

```
.gant-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
        "left right";
    grid-template-columns: max(min(20%,400px), 300px);
}

.left-panel {
    grid-area: left;
    background: grey;
}

.right-panel {
    grid-area: right;
    background: lightgray;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.right-panel-header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.right-panel-body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.gant-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    height: 30px;
}

.gant-item {
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
    min-width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
}

.weekend {
    background-color: orangered;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<div class="gant-container">
    <div class="left-panel">
        Left panel...
    </div>
    <div class="right-panel">
        <div class="right-panel-header">
            Header
        </div>
        <div class="right-panel-body">
            <div class="gant-row">
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item weekend"></div>
                <div class="gant-item weekend"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item weekend"></div>
                <div class="gant-item weekend"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="gant-row">
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item weekend"></div>
                <div class="gant-item weekend"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item weekend"></div>
                <div class="gant-item weekend"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="gant-row">
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item weekend"></div>
                <div class="gant-item weekend"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item weekend"></div>
                <div class="gant-item weekend"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `display: grid;` to `.right-panel`

```css
.gant-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
        "left right";
    grid-template-columns: max(min(20%,400px), 300px);
}

.left-panel {
    grid-area: left;
    background: grey;
}

.right-panel {
    grid-area: right;
    background: lightgray;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    display: grid;
}

.right-panel-header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.right-panel-body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.gant-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    height: 30px;
}

.gant-item {
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
    min-width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
}

.weekend {
    background-color: orangered;
}
```

```html
<div class="gant-container">
    <div class="left-panel">
        Left panel...
    </div>
    <div class="right-panel">
        <div class="right-panel-header">
            Header
        </div>
        <div class="right-panel-body">
            <div class="gant-row">
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item weekend"></div>
                <div class="gant-item weekend"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item weekend"></div>
                <div class="gant-item weekend"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="gant-row">
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item weekend"></div>
                <div class="gant-item weekend"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item weekend"></div>
                <div class="gant-item weekend"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="gant-row">
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item weekend"></div>
                <div class="gant-item weekend"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item"></div>
                <div class="gant-item weekend"></div>
                <div class="gant-item weekend"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `flex-shrink` for the flex items.

> If the size of all flex items is larger than the flex container, items shrink to fit according to flex-shrink [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink)

An example of flex shrink property:

```
 .item1{ 
    flex: 1 1 20em (shorthand for flex-grow: 1, flex-shrink: 1, 
                     flex-basis: 20em) 
 }
```

Comment: What must be the value of flex-shrink? And on which classes does this need to be set? Im current;y fiddling around with it but still can't get it fixed

Comment: It depends on the parent element size. You want the `.grant-item` to have a fixed width for that, flex-shrink determines how much to shrink if there is not enough space. If it is not set, then the default value is 1. But if you set it to 2 like this example `flex: 2 2 20em` then according to the available space the item gets twice as much space as the other items with `flex-shrink` set to 1 for them.

Comment: Can you give me a fiddle where it works?

Comment: Already got it working, see the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

The width of the `.gant-item` class for each rectangle is too large and it's essentially spilling out of your `.gant-row` element, so the border on `.right-panel-header` is fitting to the 300px you defined for the `.right-panel` container, but the container's not as wide as all the items within it.

Maybe try using a percentage as opposed to `min-width: 50px` for each `.gant-item`.

Comment: But i want the `.right-panel` to be scrollable and the `.gant-item`s to have a fixed width.